# How to download archive files from AWS S3 Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have uploaded some files to s3 and created a policy rule to migrate those files to glacier after 1 day of the creation date. My doubts,

1. How do I see whether the datas are inside s3 or glacier. (I saw after 2 days it was still in the s3)
2. If the data is moved to glacier can we be able see them in the Glacier Management console in AWS ?
3. How the Data download process will work? Was it same like downloading from s3 or not.

I was searching for these questions, Unfortunately I couldn't find a clear source. Please help if you can.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How do I see whether the datas are inside s3 or glacier. (I saw after 2 days it was still in the s3)

They files in glacier are visible in S3. You have to check their **storage class**. It should be `Glacier`.

> 2. If the data is moved to glacier can we be able see them in the Glacier Management console in AWS ?

See point 1.

> 3. How the Data download process will work? Was it same like downloading from s3 or not.

Its not like S3. To be able to download your files from Glacier, you have to [restore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/restoring-objects.html) them first. Once you do this, you will have *temporary copy** available in "regular" S3 for you to download.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Marcin . So what is the difference between mooving files from s3 to glacier via a policy rule and creating a vault from a glacier console. In that case, is the download process is same like u mentioned above for both cases?

Comment: @MohamedAhkam The vault is the "old" way of  using Glacier, separate from S3. Now glacier has been integrated with S3, before it was fully separate service. So if you want to use archives and values, then its fully independent from S3.

Comment: ok. But i guess we can download data from a vault using the aws SDK for java. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/getting-started-download-archive.html

Comment: So in that case we don't need to restore the data right? Likewise can't we directly download data from glacier without restoring? We are using "Expedited" mode for retrieval. So it will take 1-5 mins delay i guess.

Comment: @MohamedAhkam There is no such thing as "download from glacier". You have to restore first, and then you can download a copy of restored object.

Comment: here there are 4 ways to restore archives from glacier to s3. When i go to REST Api method they have used SOAP method. Are there any ways to make call from a NODE server to restore. They have shown how to restore using java and .NET with aws-sdk.